# JBoss - Cannot find tag library descriptor for Spring form

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jboss, taglib

The web application is deployed in JBoss 7 server. And spring-webmvc jar that contains spring-form.tld file is present in the classpath.

Still, below line in jsp is giving tag library not found error:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

In my application, jar files are exploded into modules/com/classpath/main/ folder. And, WEB-INF/lib folder in the ear file is empty.

Is this the reason spring-form.tld cannot be found. If so, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by extracting spring-form.tld file from the spring-webmvc jar and put it into WEB-INF/taglibs directory.

If there is any better solution for JBoss configuration explained in the question then please share.